# Using just text or images and CSS what's the best way to display a currency symbol in a textbox? (No JavaScript)

Tags: css

I would like to have a textbox with a currency symbol inside it.

I DO NOT want to use Javascript and i DO NOT want to have to deal with the symbol getting sent to the server. It is a cosmetic requirement and so would like to treat it as one.

So basically i would like to have it look like the box below.

```
[£ 0               ]
```

I have attempted this already, but it does not quite display correctly and the code looks messy (and is no doubt filled with cross browser issues).
So before i slog away and fine tune it, I hoped someone on here would know a better way.

Code so far:

```
<div style="float:left;"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { style = "padding-left: 20px;" })%></div><br />
<div style="float:left; margin-left: -190px;">£</div>
```

Many thanks,

Kohan

===

### My own implementation of accepted answer:

```
input.icon_input
{
    position:relative; 
    padding:5px; 
    padding-left:25px; 
    width:200px;
}

.input_icon
{
    display:inline-block; 
    text-align:right; 
    width:22px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    position: relative;
    left:-240px; 

}

<div>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "icon_input" })%>
    <span class="input_icon">£</span>
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I did something similar a while ago.

http://vidasp.net/CSS-examples---numbered-input-boxes.html

(check out the source code)

Comment: Very good. Although i didn't like having the textbox background transparent (since in my case the div it lives in changes color on hover). So i moved the icon to after the input and then moved that left instead of the textbox. I'll add the code to my question and mark this the answer. Many thanks.

Comment: @Kohan That is a great idea. I was curios how that would work so I created a demo. It looks great http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/input-with-pound-symbol.html

Comment: Indeed, looks very nice. I also like the right justification on the textbox, makes sense for a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `&pound;` or `&#163;` or `&#xA3;`. These codes will display the symbol. "£" :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i fear you may have misunderstood my requirements. I've got to run off and be the offices secret santa now, but i will return and try and clarify what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue that you just want the currency symbol to appear inside the visible border of the textbox?

Just use a div with a border and your currency symbol, then an input control with no border inside it, e.g.

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 20px; padding:4px; width: 200px">
$ <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="180px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox></div>
```

(I think you are using .net though I'm not sure what <%: is, guessing a typo!)

Comment: Yes, i am using .net <%: is new to 4.0 it's html encoding (For MVC)- see: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx